# Dynamic Resizing of a TGA image in a game

Tags: c++, image, opengl, direct3d

I was looking for some cool images / textures inside the files of a game and I came across the following. In this situation, the game uses the following image as the basis for an interface.

[image: First Image]

But this same image, inside the game looks like this (the base image is the larger rectangle):

[image: Second Image]

My question is: how is this possible? Given the resolution of the base image which is much smaller than that generated already inside the game, I already tried to draw a sprite with DirectX using this image as base and change the scaling of it, but I did not get a similar result. The image is blurred as if it really had been stretched in MS-Paint or something.

Comment: How do you know that the smaller image is used in the larger one?

Comment: Because i was reading the XML file that have the design code of the second image and it was pointing to the first image

Comment: Are you sure they aren't [cutting the original image into tiles to build the larger image](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/9SliceSprites.html). I'm sure there's a better link than that but it shows the idea.

Comment: @gman thank you, yeah i'm sure they are cutting the image now, can you give me one more detailed tutorial on how to do that? i'll try to find too

Comment: You create quads from triangles, you set texture coordinates to select the part of the texture you want to appear on the quads. You can make multiple quads to tile the background or cut the image into 9 parts (9 separate textures).